# Symfony 3.0 FormType: the translator doesn't work in other methods than buildForm()

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have an issue to translate "on the fly" some elements in a form class. This is very strange because the translator works perfectly for the labels of each form (in the buildForm() method) but not in the privates ones.

According to the profiler, the translator is not even called in these methods.

Here the translator is called and works:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $this->options = $options;
    $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => $this->getTranslator()->trans('Title')
            )
        )
```

But here, in the same class, it doesn't:

```
private function getMaterialList() {
    try {
        $arrResult = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Material')->findAllOrderedByNameWp();
        foreach($arrResult as $material) {
            $material->setName($this->getTranslator()->trans($material->getName()));
        }
    } catch (NoResultException $e) {
        unset($e);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $this->logger->info('Unable to list materials from booktype class ' . $ex->getMessage());
        throw new \Exception(
            $this->getTranslator()->trans('errorListingMaterials')
        );
    }

    return $arrResult;
}
```

The class (whithout extra methods):

class BookType extends AbstractType {

```
private $translator;
private $em;
private $request;
private $logger;

private function getTranslator() {

    if(!isset($this->translator)) {
        $this->translator = new Translator($this->options['locale']);
    }

    return $this->translator;
}

/**
 * List the Materials
 * 
 * @return an array of materials
 * @throws \Exception
 */
private function getMaterialList() {
    try {
        $arrResult = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Material')->findAllOrderedByNameWp();
        foreach($arrResult as $material) {
            $material->setName($this->getTranslator()->trans($material->getName()));
        }
    } catch (NoResultException $e) {
        unset($e);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $this->logger->info('Unable to list materials from booktype class ' . $ex->getMessage());
        throw new \Exception(
            $this->getTranslator()->trans('errorListingMaterials')
        );
    }

    return $arrResult;
}

/**
 * Constructor
 * 
 * @param Doctrine $doctrine
 * @param RequestStack $requestStack is the request stacl
 */
public function __construct(Doctrine $doctrine, RequestStack $requestStack, $logger) {
    $this->em = $doctrine->getManager();
    $this->request = $requestStack;
    $this->logger = $logger;        
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

    $this->options = $options;
    $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => $this->getTranslator()->trans('Title')
            )
        )
        ->add('description', TextareaType::class, array(
                'label' => $this->getTranslator()->trans('Description')
            )
        )
        ->add('year', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => $this->getTranslator()->trans('Year')
            )
        )
        ->add('editor', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Editor',
                'label' => $this->getTranslator()->trans('Editor.single'),
                'choices' => $this->getEditorList()
            )
        )
        ->add('format', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Format',
                'label' => $this->getTranslator()->trans('Format.single'),
                'choices' => $this->getFormatList()
            )
        )
        ->add('format', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Material',
                'label' => $this->getTranslator()->trans('Material'),
                'choices' => $this->getMaterialList()
            )
        )
        ->add('language', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Language',
                'label' => $this->getTranslator()->trans('Language.single'),
                'choices' => $this->getLanguageList()
            )
        )
        ->add('location', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Location',
                'label' => $this->getTranslator()->trans('Location.plural'),
                'choices' => $this->getLocationList(),
                'multiple' => true
            )
        )
        ->add('author', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Author',
                'label' => $this->getTranslator()->trans('Author.plural'),
                'choices' => $this->getAuthorList(),
                'multiple' => true
            )
        )
        ->add('kind', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Kind',
                'label' => $this->getTranslator()->trans('Kind.plural'),
                'choices' => $this->getKindList(),
                'multiple' => true
            )
        )
        ->add('isbn', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => $this->getTranslator()->trans('ISBN'),
                'required' => false
            )
        )
        ->add('keywords', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => $this->getTranslator()->trans('Keywords')
            )
        )
        ->add('slug', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => $this->getTranslator()->trans('Slug')
            )
        )  
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array(
            'label' => $this->getTranslator()->trans('Save')
        ));
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Book',
            'locale' => 'en', // the default locale
        )
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After walking through the code of the translator component, I didn't understand why this is not working.

Finally, this is what I did:

1. Upgrading from 3.0.2 to 3.1.3
2. Removed the instanciation of the component translator in my form class
3. Injected the translator component in my form class (which is declared as a service)

> site.type.book:
>           class: AppBundle\Form\BookType
>           tags:
>               - { name: form.type }
>           arguments: ['@doctrine', '@request_stack', '@logger', '@translator']